# Smallest Imperfect Graph who's chromatic number equals clique number

Tags: graph-theory

So I need to find the smallest imperfect graph, $G$ who's chromatic number equals it's clique number. ie:

$$\chi(G) = \omega(G)$$

Finding imperfect graphs isn't hard (since finding perfect graphs is). Even finding imperfect graphs with this property isn't too hard. But how do we find the *smallest* graph (I assume minimal # vertices). Even if I have an idea what this graph is, how can I prove it is the smallest? I.e if I think sum graph on $n$ vertices is the smallest graph satisfying this, it seems daunting to show every graph of order $<n$ fails to satisfy this (unless $n$ is relatively small).

Methods to approach and tackle this problem?

Comment: What is the smallest $n$ you can easily find an example for?

Comment: $C_5$ with an added internal vertex connected to 3 vertices of $C_5$, 2 of which neighbours, 1 of which is not a neighbour to either. so $n=6$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the cyclic graph with five vertices $a,b,c,d,e$ and add a sixth vertex $f$ with edges $af$, $bf$, $df$.
Then $\omega(G)=\chi(G)=3$ and the graph is not perfect becaus the induced subgraph obtained by removing $f$ has $\chi=3$ and $\omega=2$.

Why is six minimal?
For graphs up to four vertices, $\chi=\omega$ always holds, hence every graph with at most five vertices having $\chi=\omega$ is perfect.

Comment: Oh, I see you found that by yourself in a comment meanwhile.

Comment: Yes, but couldn't find a way to show it was minimal. Thanks!

Comment: Is there an easy way to show for graphs up to four verticies that X=w? I can tell it's true, but not sure if I can just state that (Ill post this as a new question, since it seems it may take some thought)

Comment: If $\omega=n$, then trivially $\omega=\chi$. If $\omega=n-1$, then colour a maximal clique with $\omega$ colours and the remaining vertex with the colour of one of its non-neighbours. If $\omega\le n-2$, then $G$ is either $C_4$ or a tree with $\chi=2$  or disconnected with $\chi=1$.

Comment: Why is the edge $df$ required? Shouldn't the example work by adding a vertex $f$ with edges $af$ and $bf$, since $a,b,f$ form a clique of size $3$?